# Why is the probability of countable set is $0$?

Tags: probability

Probability space is given as $((0,1], \mathscr F,P)$ where $P$ is defined as $P((a,b])=b-a$. 
I'm wondering why $P(A)$ is zero for any countable set $A$. Is it related to integrability? If it is, why is that?

Comment: Since $P$ is a measure it is $\sigma$-additive, so you only need to show that the probability of a singleton is zero, this is immediate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that $\{x\}$ has a probability not larger than any $(x-\frac1n,x]$, since it is a subset of these intervals for any $n\in\Bbb N$, for which $0\leq x-\frac1n$.

Therefore $P(X=x)\leq x-(x-\frac1n)=\frac1n$ for any sufficiently large $n$, and therefore $P(X=x)=0$ for any $x\in(0,1]$.

Now use the fact that $P$ is a $\sigma$-additive probability measure, namely the countable union of sets of probability $0$, has probability $0$ itself.

Answer (score 0):

What is the probability of any one point $x$? As you have pointed out, 
$$P(X = x) = P(X \in (x,x]) = x-x = 0$$

Now consider a countable set of points $\{x_i\}$, then
$$P(X\in\{x_i\}) = \sum_i P(X = x_i) = \sum_i (x_i-x_i) = 0$$

Comment: Not quite true. $x\notin (x,x]$.

Comment: Maybe this is a notation issue? I would think the inclusive right bracket would include the point, but I see what you are saying in regards to the exclusive left bracket.

Comment: $a\in(x,x]\iff x<a\leq x$. But no such $a$ exists which is both strictly larger than $x$ and less or equal to $x$. First you need to establish continuity and argue that $\{x\}=\bigcap(x-\frac1n,x]$ for $n\in\Bbb N$.